# Problems with multithread programming in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm studying Java using the book by Gosling. There is a question in the chapter devoted to the multithread programming:
    Write a program, which will create a message each second from the beginning of the session. Another thread of this program should create a message each 15 sec. You should provide the possibility of every second-notification by the thread which is counting time.
Here is my solution (it doesn't work and i can't understand why, i think, i just can't properly understand the principle on creating a thread):

```
public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
        chrono my=new chrono();
        my.timer();
        Runnable t1=new messenger(5);
        Runnable t2=new messenger(1);
        new Thread(t1, "t1").start();
        new Thread(t2, "t2").start();
    }
}

class chrono {
    static int time=0;
    public synchronized void timer() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        time++;
        System.out.println(time);
        notifyAll();
    }   
}

class messenger implements Runnable {
    int time;
    messenger(int time) {
        this.time=time;
    }
    synchronized void timerListener() {
        try {
            while (chrono.time%time!=0) {
                wait();
            }
            System.out.println("Thread "+this.time); 
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    } 
    public void run() {
        timerListener();
    }
}
```

New version:

```
public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Chronometr my=new Chronometr();
        Runnable t1=new Messenger(5, my);
        new Thread(t1, "t1").start();
        for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
            synchronized(my) {
                my.timeCount();
                my.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }

class Chronometr {
    static int time=0;
    public void timeCount() throws InterruptedException {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
        time++;
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}   
class Messenger implements Runnable{
    int time;
    public Chronometr ch;
    Messenger(int time, Chronometr ch) {
        this.time=time;
        this.ch=ch;
    }
    public void waitForTime() {
        synchronized (ch) { 
            try{
                while (Chronometr.time%time!=0)
                    ch.wait();
                System.out.println("Thread "+this.time);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        } 
    }
    public void run() {
        waitForTime();
    }
}

   Last change:


public class test {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
        Chronometr my=new Chronometr();
        Runnable t1=new Messenger(5, my);
        new Thread(t1, "t1").start();
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {

            synchronized(my) {

                Chronometr.time+=1;
                System.out.println(Chronometr.time);
                my.notifyAll();
                //my.wait();
                }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: "_it doesn't work_" Be more descriptive.

Comment: Is it possible that Runnable t1=new messenger(5); should be Runnable t1=new messenger(15);?

Comment: runtime error. (prints 1 and thread1) then halts. be more specific user.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  Just noticed another *big* problem:  The code calls Thread.sleep() inside a `synchronized` block.  No! No! No! No! No!

When I run the newer version of your program as-is, the Messenger thread usually never gets to run:  Here's what I think happens:

```
main thread              messenger thread
-----------              ----------------
starts messenger
locks chronometer
sleeps                   enters waitForTime()
                         blocks trying to lock
                           chronometer

           ---one second later---

wakes up from sleep
increments time
prints message
calls notifyAll()
  (Has no effect, 'cause
   messenger is not in
   wait() call)

ulocks the lock
re-locks the lock        wakes up
sleeps                   blocks trying to lock
                           chronometer
       .                         .
       .                         .
       .                         .
```

Try moving the Thread.sleep(1000) call out of the Chronometer.timeCount() method, into the main() method, *outside*  of the `synchronized(my)` block.  I'm guessing that the output will be more like what you expected.

Original answer below the line,

---

Your biggest problem is this:

chrono.timer() method calls notifyAll() on itself (i.e., on the chrono instance referenced by the "my" variable in main()).  Who calls wait() on that object?  Nobody is who.  Your messanger objects wait() on themselves.  Who notifies them?  Nobody is who.

Other comments (in no particular order):

(1) Class names should be CamelCase beginning with a capital letter.  The more your code looks like everybody else's, the more everybody else will be willing to try to understand it and help you out.

(2) If you have only one variable of type FooBarBaz, then the variable should be named fooBarBaz.  Same reason.

(3) Class names should be nouns (e.g., Chronometer instead of the ambiguous chrono), method names should be verbs (e.g., waitForTimerTick() instead of timerListener()).  Same reason.

(4) the `my.timer()`; call in main could not have any possible effect on the threads that you create and start after it returns.  A `foo.notify()` call does *nothing* if there are no other threads already waiting in `foo.wait()` when notify() is called.

(4a) A variable named "my" is an abomination.

(5) the `my.timer()` call waits for one second, increments my.time, notifies nobody, and then it's done.  For good.  In particular, nobody will ever increment my.time again.

(5a) The problem statement clearly says that the program should go on forever periodically printing out messages, but there are *no loops* in your program except for the `wait()` loop in messenger.timerListener().

(6) You might want to get some more experience writing single-threaded programs that solve real problems before you try to tackle threads.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I changed my code as you told (i think i at last understood this thing about wait() and notifyAll()). But it still doesn't work properly. As far as i can understand the problem is that thread t1 (the one that should show the message can't take the monitor before the main thread takes it).

Comment: I've added the new version in the main post. I'd appreciate if you can check it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for this idea - it really began to work then i extracted Thread.sleep() from synchronized block. But, it steel works partly. Here is a problem. I need to print message from thread t1 EACH 5 sec, but it is printed only one time. As far as i understand the problem is that after thread t1 got lock on Chronometr, it stops checking condition in the while() and t1 is never active again.

Comment: Changed part of code on the main thread is in main post.